# ReactJS: object is being passed to action before componentWillReceiveProps take effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object:

```
var payment = {
    method: paymentMethod,
    token: this.state.cardToken,
    amount: this.state.order_net_total,
    callback_link: callbackLink
}
```

that is part of another variable:

```
    var obj = {
        customer: {},
        delivery: {},
        payment: payment <---here
    }
```

and that variable is being passed to an action. This action is inside a function called `submit`:

```
this.props.confirmCheckout(obj)
```

now, my problem is, `this.state.cardToken` is in my `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
    if(nextProps.magpieCreateCardData.data !== this.props.magpieCreateCardData){
        if(!_.isEmpty(nextProps.magpieCreateCardData.data)){
            this.setState({
                cardToken: nextProps.magpieCreateCardData.data.id
            })
        }
    }
```

that waits for the value to change until it saves it to state. 
but when `this.props.confirmCheckout(obj)` is being executed, payment looks like this:

```
payment = {
    method: credit-card,
    token: "",
    amount: 5000,
    callback_link: http://127.0.0.1:8000
}
```

the token is empty, which is the initial state, it doesn't wait until the token gets a value. I want to know how to do that, that the action will wait until the token gets the value. It should look like this:

```
{
    method: credit-card,
    token: tok_MTU0N2MGNkMjQTg3YmU4,
    amount: 5000,
    callback_link: http://127.0.0.1:8000
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where are you calling this.props.confirmCheckout(obj)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri in a function called submit

Comment: I think you might need to disable the button until you have all the values you need to trigger the action from the button click handler

Comment: @Kabbany I can't disable them because when I click the button, there are other actions executed, one action has to be executed to get the value for the token.

Comment: so you need to trigger 2 actions, where the second one depends on the first. I think in this case you might need a redux middleware like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` to fire the second action once the first one is done.